# Different result when passing tags in pom versus maven property for cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

Short and simple.  When I pass the tags inside my pom file like below:

```
<tags><tag>@Smoke</tag></tags>
```

It works correctly.  It runs each of my scenarios that have the smoke tag independently and at the same time.

However when I pass it as a maven property like below:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"
```

It files the correct number of runners, however it runs each each scenario x number of times, where x is the number of scenarios with the tag.  So if I have 3 scenarios with the tag, it will run each test 3 times.

I'm hoping to duplicate the functionality of the first run by using properties from maven so that I can run this with Jenkins a bit easier?  Am I passing the cucumber options incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after consulting with some of the developers of the library. The tasks need to be passed:

-Dcucumber.tags="@Smoke"

Cucumber supports the way I was passing, but this library expects them like this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you accept your answer, so this question is "answered"?